# How can I test if this object returns the correct String?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a Thing class that holds various Strings and a Collection of Stuff. 
I have to test whether the Message class can correctly return **item** as **"found"** in a MessageTest class.

What is the most elegant/efficient way of testing this?

What kind of fake object should I create, and how do I test with/against it?

```
public class Thing
{
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;
    public String d;
    public String e;
    public Collection<Stuff> collection;
}

public class Message
{
    private String item;

    public Message(Thing thing)
    {
        for (Stuff stuff : thing.collection)
        {
            if (stuff.getItem().equals("key"))
            {
                item = "found";
            }
        }
    }


@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(a);
    builder.append(b);
    builder.append(c);
    builder.append(d);
    builder.append(e);
    builder.append(item);
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I've personnaly read this nice tutorial about jUnit and found it very clear and well written : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to fake anything.  Just have each of your test-cases construct a suitable `Thing`, pass it into a `Message`, and then assert on the contents of the `toString` result.

Comment: I would assume that `Message` either does something with `item` or exposes it through a getter. That's what I'd assert. I wouldn't assert on `toString()`, because many people (including me) only use it informally, for logging and debugging. Hence its format might change for reasons completely unrelated to the functionality you want to test. And you don't want to have to adapt your test every time that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of JUnit is to do unit testing. I think you should test a specific method that you know what it should do instead of "faking" anything (I understand `mocking` for faking), for example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PayrollTesCase {

    @Test
    public void testCalculate() {
        Message m = new Message(new Thing("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
        assertEquals("abcde", m.toString());
    }

}
```

So, if in the future you change your Message.toString() implementation, you introduced a bug and it returns "cde" then your specific test case will fail. This is the idea behind unit testing.

I like this definition:

> Unit Testing is a level of the software testing process where
>   individual  units/components of a software/system are tested. The
>   purpose is to validate  that each unit of the software performs as
>   designed.

In JUnit 4.x all the methods are annotated. So, the flow of control in JUnit methods can be described as below:

```
@BeforeClass -> @Before -> @Test -> @After -> @AfterClass
```

By the way, you have different degrees of testing, Unit Testing is the "smallest". I'm not sure what you need but maybe you want to do an Integration Test.

[image: software testing hierarchy]